# Errors after migrating a Drupal 6 to Pressflow

Tags: views, 6

After I migrated a Drupal 6 site to Pressflow, my page started to show the following error messages:

> Notice: Undefined variable: split_sub_menu in st_core_preprocess_page() (line 58 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_validate() should be compatible with that of views_handler::options_validate() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_submit() should be compatible with that of views_handler::options_submit() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter_boolean_operator::value_validate() should be compatible with that of views_handler_filter::value_validate() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_style_default::options() should be compatible with that of views_object::options() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_validate() should be compatible with that of views_plugin::options_validate() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_submit() should be compatible with that of views_plugin::options_submit() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in custom_breadcrumbs_home_crumb() (line 541 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\custom_breadcrumbs\custom_breadcrumbs.module).
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _custom_breadcrumbs_create_crumb_items() (line 574 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\custom_breadcrumbs\custom_breadcrumbs.module).
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _custom_breadcrumbs_create_crumb_items() (line 582 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\custom_breadcrumbs\custom_breadcrumbs.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in custom_breadcrumbs_home_crumb() (line 541 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\custom_breadcrumbs\custom_breadcrumbs.module).
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _custom_breadcrumbs_create_crumb_items() (line 574 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\custom_breadcrumbs\custom_breadcrumbs.module).
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _custom_breadcrumbs_create_crumb_items() (line 582 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\custom_breadcrumbs\custom_breadcrumbs.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: pager_container in template_preprocess_ddblock_cycle_block_content() (line 1643 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\ddblock\ddblock.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: pager_event in template_preprocess_ddblock_cycle_block_content() (line 1644 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\ddblock\ddblock.module).
>   Notice: Undefined variable: count_sidebar_left in st_core_set_regions() (line 373 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_argument::init() should be compatible with that of views_handler::init() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method views_many_to_one_helper::option_definition() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in views_handler_argument_many_to_one->option_definition() (line 35 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_argument_many_to_one.inc).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method views_many_to_one_helper::option_definition() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in views_handler_argument_many_to_one->option_definition() (line 35 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_argument_many_to_one.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: quicktabs_tabpage in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 212 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: count in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 212 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: width in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: width in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined variable: count_sidebar_left in st_core_set_regions() (line 373 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter_term_node_tid::value_validate() should be compatible with that of views_handler_filter::value_validate() in views_include_handler() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: content_bottom_home_left in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 212 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: count in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 212 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: width in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: width in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in view::load() (line 906 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: content_bottom_home_right in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 212 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: count in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 212 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: width in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: width in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$display_handler in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_admin_link() (line 371 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\admin\admin.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: total in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 214 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: width in st_core_preprocess_block() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\themes\sttheme\st_core\template.php).

Comment: What version of Pressflow?  Where in the process did you get this error?

Comment: pressflow 6.25 my drupal vesion 6.25 working correct

Answer (score 1):

Is the site working apart from displaying those errors? They are all non-critical; you could set your [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) value to not display E_NOTICE and E_STRICT

Comment: Pressflow 6 will throw a billion E_NOTICE if you don't disable them.

Comment: So will Drupal without Pressflow, in my experience.

Comment: how can i disable E_NOTICE?

Answer (score 1):

> Strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called
>   statically in view::load() (line 906 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pressflow\sites\all\modules\views\views.module).

for the above error you can write it as

```
 $r = new view();   
 $view = $r ->load($name, $reset);
```